# Winning strategy writing a binary number

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

A and B play by turns to write ones and zeros in a list, from left to right.The game ends when each has written 2013 numbers.When the game ends the sequence of numbers is seen as the expansion of a binary number.A wins if that number can be written as the sum of two perfect squares and B win otherwise.Who has the winning strategy and what is the winning strategy ?

Comment: Olympiad problem, Bulgaria 2001: http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=2btDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I wasn't allowed to see the page from the book when I clicked through.

Answer (score 2):

Two helpful results:

1. If $n$ is the sum of two squares then $n\not\equiv 3\pmod 4$.
2. If $4n$ is the sum of two squares then $n$ is the sum of two squares.

(To see the second claim, note that $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod 4$ is only possible with $a,b$ both even)

**Lemma 1.**  If A ever picks $1$, B can force a win.

*Proof.* We show by induction on $k\in\mathbb N$ that if A picks $1$ in any of the last $k$ moves, B wins.
Assume A's last move is $1$. If B then also picks $1$, the resulting number is $\equiv 3\pmod 4$ and B wins. This shows the claim for $k=1$.
Assume the claim is true for $k$.
Now assume A picks $1$ in his $(k+1)$ last move. Then B can reply with $1$. By induction hypothesis we can assume that the remaining $k$ moves by A are all $0$. If B also picks $0$ for the remaining $k$ moves, the resulting number is a power of $4$ times a number $\equiv 3\pmod 4$, hence not the sum of two squares and B wins. $_\square$

**Lemma 2.** If A never picks $1$, B can force a win.

*Proof.* Assume A always picks $0$. Then B can achieve that the resulting digit sequence is $0\ldots010101$, i.e. the resulting number is $21$ and not the sum of two squares. $_\square$

**Corollary.** B can force a win. $_\square$

In fact, we can formulate an explcit strategy for B:
If the number so far is $\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_{4021}$ or $\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_{4021}10$ or $\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{4021}1010$, pick $1$. In all other cases do the same move A just did.

Comment: can the problem be extented.... who has a winning strategy if the game is started with a given sequence of binary numbers?

Comment: @JoyentanujDas Lemma 1 still holds. In order to adapt lemma 2, it is sufficient if there are at least four rounds after the given bit pattern. "Divisible by $3$, but not by $9$" would be sufficient.  The result is divsible by $3$ if B picks the right *number* of $1$s in the last four rounds (and if zero/four $1$s would be okay, so would be three/one); swap consecutive $0$ and $1$ moves to deals with divisibility by $9$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: one particular phrase in that paragraph stands out as being more complex than the rest....